# Convert 'bytes' object to string

Tags: python, string, encoding

I tried to find solution, but still stuck with it.
I want to use PyVisa to control function generator.
I have a `waveform` which is a list of values between `0` and `16382`
Then I have to prepare it in a way that each `waveform` point occupies 2 bytes.
A value is represented in big-endian, MSB-first format, and is a straight binary. So I do `binwaveform = pack('>'+'h'*len(waveform), *waveform)`
And then when I try to write it to the instrument with `AFG.write('trace ememory, '+ header + binwaveform)` I get an error:

```
  File ".\afg3000.py", line 97, in <module>
    AFG.write('trace ememory, '+ header + binwaveform)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

I tried to solve it with `AFG.write('trace ememory, '+ header + binwaveform.decode())` but it looks that by default it tries to use ASCII characters what is not correct for some values: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 52787: invalid start byte`

Could you please help with it?

Comment: The error is arising because you are trying to concatenate a `str` with a `bytes` object. I am unfamiliar with the library you are using, but I suspect the function takes `bytes`.

Comment: Yes @AlastairMcCormack explained how to convert it. `write` function takes strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binwaveform` is a packed byte array of an integer. E.g:

```
struct.pack('<h', 4545)
b'\xc1\x11'
```

You can't print it as it makes no sense to your terminal. In the above example, 
`0xC1` is invalid ASCII and UTF-8.

When you append a byte string to a regular str (`trace ememory, '+ header + binwaveform`), Python wants to convert it to readable text but doesn't know how.

Decoding it implies that it's text - it's not.

The best thing to do is print the hex representation of it:

```
import codecs
binwaveform_hex = codecs.encode(binwaveform, 'hex')
binwaveform_hex_str = str(binwaveform_hex)
AFG.write('trace ememory, '+ header + binwaveform_hex_str)
```

Comment: `binwaveform_hex` was still a byte array, not accepted by the `write` function, so I do `AFG.write('trace ememory, '+ header + str(binwaveform_hex)).
No more error in python, but no writing effect on AFG side. But it has to be something else... Thanks a lot!